# Return List of Enum values from string literal of Enum's name

Tags: java, reflection, enums

Let's say I have a string with a value

```
'Language'
```

And I have an enum called Language

```
enum Language{
    English,
    Spanish,
    French
}
```

Is there a way to use the string 'Language' and return the values of the Enum Language. I'm basically wondering if there is a method to get an instance of the Enum Language by passing in a string. Kind of like

```
Class.forName()
```

but for enums.

Comment: Ignore my close, this is java (oops)

Comment: Maybe this is the answer?  I don't know java as well and can't test: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4751239/215752

Answer (score 6):

An enum is a class, so with the fully qualified name (eg, `"com.mydomain.myapp.Language"`) you can get the enum's class from `Class.forName`. From there, you can use reflection on the Class object: [getEnumConstants](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants%28%29) gives you all the enum's values, and if you want names instead you can just use [.name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name%28%29) on the Enum objects.

Comment: what is com.mydomin.myapp? Plus my enum is in a package so how do I include that in the name

Comment: Fully qualified name of class [as in docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)).

Comment: I think it is the correct answer and just want to add another link with the tutorial from Oracle showing just how to use reflection to get the values : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/enumMembers.html

Comment: I've never really understood fully qualified class name. If my app is called Notebook and the enum is called Language in a package called Notes, what would the fully qualified name be?

Comment: @Daniel: you have tons of Java tutorials explaining that, eg http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html