# NoSuchMethodError for calling an Enum subclass type's valueOf() with reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, enums, static-methods, value-of

Luckily, to solve this problem of mine, I could use [Java: instantiating an enum using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735927/java-instantiating-an-enum-using-reflection) (the following line: `Enum.valueOf((Class<Enum>) class.forName("me.example.enums.MyEnumType"), value);` ), however I am still curious why it didn't work initially.

I tried calling my own Enum subclass's `valueOf(String)` method using reflection, but it threw a `NoSuchMethodError`.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: me.example.enums.MyEnumType.valueOf()
```

A **minimal example** is the following:

```
package me.example.enums;

public enum MyEnumType
{
    THIS,
    THAT;
}
```

and

```
package me.example;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String enumClassPath = "me.example.enums.MyEnumType";
        Object object;
        try
        {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(enumClassPath);
            Method method = clazz.getMethod("valueOf");
            object = method.invoke(null, "THAT");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Which throws:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: me.example.enums.MyEnumType.valueOf()
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at me.example.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:15)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: me.example.enums.MyEnumType.valueOf()
    at me.example.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: me.example.enums.MyEnumType.valueOf()
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at me.example.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:15)
```

I thought `valueOf()` was a static method, why does it not exist? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Class#valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...)) needs a `String` parameter:

```java
Method method = clazz.getMethod("valueOf", String.class);
```